# How to restore a DD image file in my primary disk on new debian server

Tags: debian, ssh, dd, restore

I have a dedicated Debian server at Online.net and I want to change the server by a more powerful (always Debian OS). For that, I have made an image on my old hard disk with this command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -c > /backup/sda1_image.gz
```

In my 2 machines, I don't have partitions and I have just one hard disk.

My question :

How I can to restore my image in my new Debian server, on his primary disk? It's possible to make it in ssh:

```
gzip -cd /backup/sda1_image.gz | dd of=/dev/sda
```

Question: I have to unmount my primary disk before the restoration ?
Question: If I unmount the primary(boot) disk by ssh, it not freeze ? Because I just can access to my server in ssh (no phisical).

Comment: A couple of comments. First, you could use fsarchiver, which is better than dd in my opinion, and handles writing to the disk more smoothly. Second, use xz for compression - you get smaller images. You are zipping it up to copy ot the remote server, right? BTW, I'm unclear how you plan to replace the whole OS remotely (if that is what you are trying to do). You normally need to do such thing locally with a live CD or similar.

Comment: For whole disk images you usually want a compression that's fast more than one that makes small files. That's why I always preferred gzip over bzip2, not sure how xz performs there. As for your question @Dimi it's unclear, `dd if=source | gzip > img.gz` and `gunzip < img.gz | dd of=target` works fine, but you pretty much wrote that already. So what's the problem? SSH? `ssh user@sourcehost cat img.gz | gunzip | dd of=target`

Comment: Thanks you Faheem for your reply. I can't launch a live CD because I doesn't have access to my dedicated server. I can just use SSH. Sorry if I'm not clear, I want to copy at the identical my old HD to my new HD (service and data).

Comment: If "SSH" is not an installed system but a rescue system, it should work fine. Otherwise, you have to remount everything readonly first...

Comment: After use this command `gzip -cd /backup/sda1_image.gz | dd of=/dev/sda` if I reboot the server that's work ?

Comment: @frostschutz Why are you using `dd`? `gunzip <img.gz >/dev/sda` should do the job just fine.

Comment: instead of dd I would have use cat but it almost the same I guess. but don't forget to fisrt mount your old disk in Read only befoire doing any backup

Comment: Thanks all. What are the commands to restore my image disk in the new server ? I want to retrieve all services... I don't want to reinstate all services.

Answer (score 2):

You can SSH to your server, CAT your file into a pipe to GUNZIP after what you can pipe the uncompressed output to DD, which will then write the file to the disk of your choice.

```
ssh user@host cat /path/to/image.img.gz | gunzip | sudo dd of=/dev/sdX
```

You can also improve on this by using PIGZ (Parallel Gzip) instead of GUNZIP to decompress your file. This is better since PIGZ uses all your processing cores while GUNZIP uses only 1. (Note you would need to install PIGZ before using it)

```
ssh user@host cat /path/to/image.img.gz | pigz -dc | sudo dd of=/dev/sdX
```

You can also show the progress of DD by adding status=progress at the end your your DD command.

```
ssh user@host cat /path/to/image.img.gz | pigz -dc | sudo dd of=/dev/sdX status=progress
```

Comment: This would overwrite /dev/sdX on the HOST, not the remote server, no?